# Sorting numbers and dates in a KGrid

Tags: delphi, gridview, lazarus, sorting

I have a KGrid in a Lazarus project that contains different columns with numeric, text and date data.

Sorting by the column with text data is OK but sorting by the columns containing numeric or date data does not work at all.

For instance

10,2,3,1,4,21,30 is sorted as 1,10,2,21,3,30,4 in that order.

Does anyone use KGrid and is there a way to change the grid's OnCompareCells event so that the sorting is done correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know KGrid (not a Lazarus user), but you have to convert the data to the proper type and do your comparison on them that way. (By this I mean you have to convert the two Cell values to integer and compare the integers, or convert them both to `TDateTime` and compare them as `TDateTime` values.) The standard Delphi `TStringGrid` doesn't support column sorting, so I can't provide exact info how to use `OnCompareCells` to do so (which is why I'm posting a comment and not an answer).

Comment: Post the code you use to sort it right now.  My best guess is you would set the comparison result to be like this: `result := StrToIntDef(s1,-9999)-StrToIntDef(s2,-9999)` where s1 and s2 are the string values you're comparing, and you subtract those integers to get a comparison.

Comment: I've solved the problem. I used TryStrToInt, TryStrToDate, TryStrToFloat and TryStrToTime. I wrote a custom function to override the default OnCompareCells event of the KGrid and now sorting works properly.